# Problem with show_error() in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem with my codeigniter app.
Everytime i want to use show_error() i got the following error message:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_Exceptions::$load
>
> Filename: errors/error_general.php
>
> Line Number: 2
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function helper() on a non-object in .../application/errors/error_general.php on line 2

I dont really know how to fix this

any ideas?

Comment: Looks like CI is not fully initialized at the time you want to use the `show_error()` function. Which CI version are you using?

Comment: @skelle Did you make any modification to the error_general.php file? because there's no such thing as a function call there...Did you modified the html, substituting it with the html helper function, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells the tale...

You must have some custom code in the error file trying to load a helper. The default error template only uses a couple of variables and doesn't reference the CI_Controller instance (which may not be instantiated yet).

Somewhere in the file you are using `$this->load->helper()`, but `$this` is a reference to `CI_Exceptions` in that scope.

**How to fix it:**

Use a static error template, or use something other than `show_error()` if possible. Perhaps write your own function for use *after* you know Codeigniter is loaded and you have access to classes and helpers.